# .net service in Windows XP slow to start on Windows Startup

Tags: .net

I have a .net service that starts up with Windows properly in all versions of Windows except for XP.  My .net service will start in XP, but it waits until the "Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN V4.0.30319_X86" service has started and stopped, and then my service will load.  But this can take up to a minute or so.  Any ideas on how I can make my service not wait for the NGEN service to start and stop before running my service?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708846%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Hans, thank you for the info!  Are you saying to look at the NGEN logs to see if there is a clue there?  I looked at the NGEN.log and NGEN_service.log, but nothing has been logged since the OS was installed.

Comment: I guess Hans is busy, does anyone else know?